# primefaces: managedbean constructor called before actionlistner

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have created managed bean (CourtUitility.java) with two property court(object of CourtBean.java) and courtAll(List object contains arraylist of courtbean). 
My code is as below 
CourtUitility.java

```
@ManagedBean 
@RequestScoped
public class CourtUitility {

private CourtBean court =new CourtBean();
private List<CourtBean> courtAll = new ArrayList<CourtBean>();
/** Creates a new instance of CourtUitility */

public CourtUitility() {
    courtAll = new ArrayList<CourtBean>();
    int userID = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("USER_ID").toString());
    courtAll = CourtService.GenerateCourtList(userID);
}

public CourtBean getCourt() {
    return court;
}

public void setCourt(CourtBean court) {
    this.court = court;
}

public List<CourtBean> getCourtAll() {
    return courtAll;
}

public void setCourtAll(List<CourtBean> courtAll) {
    this.courtAll = courtAll;
}

public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
     court.setUserID(Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("USER_ID").toString()));
    System.out.println("Court ID : " + court.getCourtID());
    System.out.println("User ID : " + court.getUserID());
    CourtService.AddCourt(court);
    court = new CourtBean();
    courtAll = CourtService.GenerateCourtList(Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("USER_ID").toString()));
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Court Record Created", "");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
}
```

clientMaster.xhtml

```
<ui:composition template="/template/mainLayout.xhtml" >
        <ui:define name="pageContent">
 <h:form id="co">
                <p:growl life="5000" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" id="courtmessage" />
                <p:panel id="courtDetail" header="Court Details">
                    <p:messages id="panelMessage" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" autoUpdate="true" globalOnly="true" />

                    <h:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="grid">
......
<p:commandButton id="addCourt" immediate="true" value="Add Court" actionListener="#{courtUitility.save}" update=":co,:cot" async="true" >
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>
<ui:include id="abc" src="CourtEditDatatable.xhtml"/> 
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

When I enter submit form through commandbutton all data gets null in database.
After debugging I found that, when submit form, managed bean constructor call first and all properties are reinitialized. After that action listener is called so it gets null in database.
I have also tried with view scope but problem remains same. 
Is there any possible way to stop calling constructor while action listener called???

One more thing to share I have created client master with wizard in same project with same pattern. It is working fine. It is not causing problem while saving record.
Is it due to wizard??

Comment: if the bean is @ViewScoped, then it's constructed when the page is loaded, not when action is invoked. are you sure you add the right imports? also you can try to clean & build the project and then re deploy

Comment: thnx Damian it works after redeploy. I think it my IDE problem.

Answer (score 3):

> *Is there any possible way to stop calling constructor while action listener called???*

If you stop the construction of the bean, then there would be no bean instance at all and JSF would not be able to invoke the action on the bean. So, no, this does not make any sense.

Your problem is caused elsewhere. Too bad that your form is incomplete, but I at least see an `immediate="true"` on the submit button. I'm not sure why you need this on a "Save" button, this is more typical for a "Cancel" button. If you do *not* have this attribute on any of the input fields in the same form, then they will **not** be processed at all.

Remove the `immediate="true"` from the button and JSF will process the submitted input values and they will be set in the bean during update model values phase the usual way.